# Adding internal A-record to a second level domain

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, routing, domain

Just a though- if I add my internal IP address to A-record to a second level domain.com (assuming that I can't add it internally using AD/DNS)

Will it work in my internal network?

Theoretically, any PC in internal network will send a request to external DNS server when my domain.com is called; external DNS will shoot back an IP(internal); so the IP is reachable internally; should work?

Am not trying to use internal DNS nor Implement it. I am wondering if I can go around it.
The main goal is to use mydomain.com internally which would be reachable from any internal computer

Comment: If, as you say, you can't add to your internal DNS, then how do you expect to add an a-record to it? If you just asking if you can set up an internal DNS to provide internal IPs and forward all other requests, then yes you can do it, and there's a few questions on here regarding that.  As-is this one is too broad (IMO). What have you tried already? Where are you getting stuck exactly? PS: no one owes you an explanation for their down-votes, perhaps hover over the down-vote arrow to get an idea as to why they may have clicked it. :)

Comment: I am not trying to use internal DNS nor Implement it. I am wondering if I can go around it.

Comment: Yeah, your question is very unclear. :)  So you're talking about adding your internal IP address to an external DNS server hosted outside your network, so that when you use the domain name within the LAN, it returns the local (LAN-level) IP?  And you don't expect this to work outside of said LAN, right? :)  Why not just use the HOSTS file on your PC(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. If you own "example.com" and have access to manage it's DNS records, then you can point "example.com" to 127.0.0.1 or any other IP address.

Here, I set up a live example for you. Look up the IP address of `localhost.gwhois.org`. (You can use my tool if you want: https://gwhois.org/dns/localhost.gwhois.org)

I have it pointed to 127.0.0.1.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

What you are suggesting should work.

But, as an alternative, I'd suggest you use your operating system's [HOSTS file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29) instead, and add an entry for your chosen host name, pointing at the desired IP address.

HOSTS files are checked before DNS.

Comment: hosts file would be helpful for 1 pc, but when there are dozens its an administrative hassle... Plus I have no access to hosts as well.

Comment: If you can't change ANYTHING about the computer or the network, you're pretty much out of luck and your question is unanswerable.  I'd discuss this with your IT.  If it's a company system that you have no control over, then you're not going to be able to specify a different DNS server to use, and if you do manage to pull it off, then it can be considered an attempt to circumvent company polices, and may get you fired.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this would work pretty much as you expect. If you control a DNS domain, you can create `A` records within the domain which resolve to any address that you like. You could buy your own domain for the purpose, or use a service like [DYNDNS](http://dyndns.org/). In fact, this is the original purpose of services like DYNDNS--It gave people using residential broadband service a way to attach a permanent hostname to their IP address, even if their ISP doesn't offer such a service.

Comment: no, it is a corporate network. I want to make an internal-use site using second level domain without involving change control

Comment: I'm not sure what your point is. Like I said, it'd work.